# Without re-writing Python/Perl scripts, how would I pipe outputs together in a bash script?

Tags: python, linux, bash, perl, shell

I have the following Perl scripts (though this applies to Python and other scripting languages): `script1.pl`, `script2.pl`, `script3.pl`

The way these scripts were written, users execute them with input flags, and the output is a file saved.

```
perl script1.pl --i input1.tsv   ## this outputs the file `outputs1`
perl script2.pl --i outputs1     ## this outputs the file `outputs2`
perl script3.pl --i outputs2     ## this outputs the file `final_output`
```

(For Pythonistas, this is `python script1.py`)

Now, I would like to create an executable bash script that allows users to simply work with `input1` and get the output in return `final_output`.

Here's how I would do this with only one perl script, `execute.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

source ~/.bash_profile

FLAG1="--i=$1"

perl script1.pl $FLAG1
```

which could be run on the command line `execute.sh input1.tsv`

For my example with three scripts, how would I pipe the intermediate outputs into the intermediate scripts to created one `execute.sh` script, e.g. `outputs1` into `script2.pl`, then `outputs2` into `scripts3.pl`, etc.?

Is there a way for me to do this without rewriting the perl/python scripts?

EDIT: Additional information: The problem is I actually don't know what outputs is. The file name changes based on the original inputs1.tsv. Now, it is true that I know the file extension of the outputs. But outputs1 and outputs2 have the same file extension.

Comment: by calling the scripts with the correct filenames, the same as when doing it by hand, except it's in a script. No magic neeed.

Comment: Do the scripts require specific input/output files? Typically you’d just pipe them together as `< input1.tsv perl script1.pl | perl script2.pl | perl script3.pl > outputs2` (and write the scripts so that’s possible, of course)

Comment: If the script always outputs to a hard-wired file name, there's no other way than to change the script.

Comment: Can you please explain why simply running the three commands in a row in your bash script doesn't work?

Comment: @merlin2011 The problem is I actually don't know what `outputs` is. The file name changes based on the original `inputs1.tsv`. Now, it is true that I know the file extension of the outputs. But `outputs1` and `outputs2` have the same file extension.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, Is the output file name a deterministic function of the input name? If so, you could do the transformation inside your bash script.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang that would be good information to have in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice for cases like this is to have the scripts read from stdin and write to stdout. In that case, it becomes very easy to pipe them together, like this:

```
perl script1.pl < input1.tsv | perl script2.pl | perl script3.pl
```

In your case, you could write a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
perl script1.pl --i input1.tsv
perl script2.pl --i outputs1 
perl script3.pl --i outputs2
```

It's not ideal, but it would do what you want. It would read input1.tsv, and write outputs3.

Comment: "In your case, you could write a script like this" see comments above. The problem is I actually don't know what outputs is. The file name changes based on the original inputs1.tsv. Now, it is true that I know the file extension of the outputs. But outputs1 and outputs2 have the same file extension.

Comment: `perl script1.pl < input1.tsv | perl script2.pl | perl script3.pl`

I may be missing something. The script works by `perl script.pl --i input`. How does ``perl script1.pl < input1.tsv | perl script2.pl ` pipe the output of `perl script1.pl` to be read correctly by `perl script2.pl`?

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you had the opportunity to write it from scratch yourself, I'd recommend writing it so that it read from stdin and wrote to stdout--then you wouldn't have any constraints on the filenames. If you don't know and can't predict the names of the output files of the various scripts, it makes it hard to automate. You could do things like capture the names of all the files in the directory, run the script, capture the names again, and see what's changed. That's getting a little ridiculous, but it sounds like you might not have a lot of better options...

Answer (score -1):

Your question doesn't say this, but assuming you may specify the output file using a `--o` flag:

```
perl script1.pl --i input1.tsv --o /dev/stdout | perl script2.pl --i /dev/stdin --o /dev/stdout | perl script3.pl --i /dev/stdin --o final_output
```

`/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stdout` are magical unix files that write to the process’ `stdin` and `stdout` respectively.

Comment: Unfortunately, I would have to write a `--o` flag

Comment: Yep, if the script is just hard-coded to some filename then you're pretty much screwed!